# Краткое описание товара в рекомендуемых

Tags: php, вёрстка

Добрый день. Делаю магазин на OpenCart 1.5.4.1. Возникла необходимость на главной, в рекомендуемых товарах выводить краткое описание (под названием товара). Но не знаю как этого добиться. Подскажите, пожалуйста, что мне делать? Заранее спасибо. Вот мой магазин - http://fishing-trade.com/

Comment: А зачем нам ваш магазин? Даже смотреть не буду. А на вопрос "что мне делать", есть два логичных ответа: или "учиться", или "нанять за денежку специалиста"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для краткого описания используйте первые 50-100 символов от полного описания.
естественно смотрите чтобы это было не пол слова.
Как это сделать?
Не сложно как Вам тут уже советовали или учитесь сами писать под движок своего магазина или наймите специалиста.
А возможно при помощи поисковой системы найдете, уже готовый код под движок вашего магазина.

Comment: Благодарю!